# Why do I get FileNotFoundError when using subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, bash, cmd, grep, cut

I try to execute a `ping` process from python:

```
import subprocess

with open('ips') as f:
    line = f.readlines()
for i in line:
results=subprocess.Popen(["ping -c 1" +  i])
print(results)
```

It fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python_test.py", line 9, in <module>
results=subprocess.Popen(["ping -c 1" +  i])
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1289, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ping -c 110.11.1.1\n'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) just returns an exit code—just the number 0 if it worked, some other number if there was an error. Is that really what you want? If not, do what the docs say and [use the `subprocess` module instead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements).

Comment: Meanwhile, "having this error"… what error? You have to show it to us (and make sure to paste the whole traceback) if you want us to debug it.

Comment: i think, i have to use subprocess module. instead of os.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want use the `Popen` method, then the program name and arguments need to be separate elements of the list, like this:

```
for i in lines:
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c 2', i], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    # Run the command
    output = p1.communicate()[0]
    print(output)
```

Read from the official document, may be the `run` method more used.

The official document

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Thanks bro, its working fine but the only thing is its slow.